# Going and returning ticket bought differently

Tags: visas, transit, tickets

I had issues about transit which has been explained to me by you all: [I wasn't allowed to check in for my flight because I didn't have a Turkish transit visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/122615/19400).

On my ticket, the going side has transit to Istanbul with different airports:  Atatürk to SAW. But the returning side has the transit on the same airport: Atatürk, and I will continue my journey from the same airport Atatürk, which means I won't be needing a transit visa for the returning, but the going side requires a transit visa because is different airports. My question:
Is it possible for me to get another ticket for just going and then I will return with the first ticket I bought, because the returning side of the ticket has one airport but the going side has different airports and I don't have Turkish transit visa?

Answer (score 3):

You will have to call the issuer of the ticket to arrange this.  If you don't call first, then missing any flight will normally cause the remainder of the ticket to be cancelled.  The airline may charge a change fee, but it's also possible that they'll allow you to retain the return flight without taking the outbound flight.

Regardless, you should call them and explain what you would like to do.  Then, if they say that you will have to pay extra to do it, you can weigh that cost against the cost of buying a new ticket.

You may also want to ask whether you can change your outbound flight to one that does not require changing airports.  That might be less expensive than buying a new ticket (or it might be more expensive, but you won't know unless you ask).

Answer (score 1):

It is complicated:

1. If you want to change or cancel your outbound flight, you may have to pay change fee. If you just don't board the flight, your return flight will be cancelled
2. Your return flight may also require a transit visa, depending on the way its booked. If it's two separate tickets, you still may have to collect your bags in Istanbul and go through customs and immigration before you can check in again. If it's a single ticket your bags are probably checked through and you can stay airside.